# SQL Server 2016 export top 500k rows from 4 million row table

Tags: sql-server

I'm testing different SSIS packages on different tables. Therefore I want to use tables with a different number of rows. I used SQL Data Generator to create data. I thought that I can fill one table with 4 Million rows and then use

```
INSERT INTO 500kTable SELECT TOP (500000) * FROM 4MillionTable
```

to copy the first 500k rows to another table. The problem now is that SQL Server (2016 Enterprise) only copies 111.110 rows and then finishes the command. Also exporting the data to a flat file will only export 111.110 rows. Is there a way to export or copy more data? Filling the other tables with the data via SQL Data Generator is using to much time, because I have to map everything again. Or is there a way in SQL Data Generator to copy the settings for one table to another table?

Comment: Have you considered the possibility that your table contains only 111.110 rows? What does `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM 4MillionTable` return?

Comment: No I didn't consider this because I set the data gen to 4 Million rows. It seems like this is the case and it stopped after 111.110 rows. Thank you for the hint!